# Can npm 5 have --no-save as default?

Tags: npm, npm-install

Is it possible to get npm 5 to use the old behaviour of not saving the installed dependency without adding the switch?

I.e. I'm used to `npm install <package>` not modifying `package.json`, and I like to keep it that way?

Some global setting?

Answer (score 3):

```
npm config set save false
```

Should disable auto-save